# mvc3 search results with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I am working on a Asp.Net MVC3 webapplication.I have a textbox and a button. I use a MVC WebGrid to display data in UI based on the search string. I am trying to pull mvc webgrid with out page postback using jquery. I need some help in Jquery code to populate data with out post back.

What I am doing right now is jquery on button click or on selected item I am taking selected id an redirecting to page again as below.

```
 select: function (event, ui) { 
                $.ajax({ url: 'ControllerName', 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: { id: ui.item.id 
                    }, 
                    async: false, 
                    success: function (result) { 
                        window.location.replace("ControllerName" + '?id=' + ui.item.id); 
                    } 
                });
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The "result" variable is an object that contains the response from the server. If the response was HTML you could update the page content by either appending the response to the page or replacing an entire HTML section. Keep in mind that in jQuery 1.8 the way you're using your AJAX requests will be replaced with a different method.

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.5. Is there any option in get Razor data displayed with this version. Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to give you an example

Comment: Nick Give me some time for testing this. Thanks a Ton for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

With the use of the `$.support` (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) you can check to see if AJAX is enabled or not:

```
 $.support.ajax
```

Once we know if AJAX is enabled or not we can build a smart search button. Lets setup your Controller/Actions in MVC:

```
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{
     //TODO: Some logic to perform a search
     MySearchResultsModel results = new MySearchResultsModel(); //Populate results with some model of data

     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
          return PartialView("_Results", results); //partial view w/ results
     else
          return View("Search",results); //Returns a full page
}
```

Now that our controller action is setup to perform a search we need two different views:

- A partial view that will render out the HTML of your search results (called "_Results")
- A full view that will wrap the partial view incase the browser doesn't (called Search")
  support AJAX

Now, the "Search" page would look something like:

```
@model MySearchResultsModel
<h2>Search Results</h2>
@Html.Partial("_Results",model)
```

The "_Results" would contain either raw HTMl or make use of your MVC WebGrid:

```
 @model  MySearchResultsModel
 <ul>
 @foreach(var result in MySearchResultsModel.Results)
 {
      <li>@result.SomeProperty</li>
 }
 </ul>
```

Now, how to make it all work? Lets say your page has a div on it with an id of "searchResults":

```
 <div id="searchResults"></div>
```

And you'll need a form for the search:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("Search")" id="searchForm">
      <input type="text" name="q" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
 </form>
```

And you'll need some JS to capture the form submit

```
 $(function(){
      $('#searchForm').submit(function(e){
           if($.support.ajax) //Is AJAX enalbed?
           {
                e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting

               //Send the request via AJAX
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).attr('action'), //Read the action from the FORM url OR you could use @Url.Action('Search')
                    data: $(this).serialize(),  //The forms data
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#searchResults').html(response); //This sets the DIV's contents to the AJAX response
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('An error occured while performing your search');
                    }
                });

           } 
      });
 });
```